# Define varying ranges in for next loop

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to define a range that changes according to a value in a `For` loop and the values of this range to another sheet.

Here is the code.

```
For i = 2 To 161672
  If cgmfitbit.Worksheets(1).Cells(i, 2).Value = ptnames Then
    ptfile.Worksheets(1).Range("A" & i & ":P" & i).Value = cgmfitbit.Worksheets(1).Range("A" & i & ":P" & i).Value
  End If
Next i
```

I am getting a run time error 91.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4660142/11683)

Comment: @GSerg - this is a [tag:vba] question, so a [tag:.net] answer will not be appropriate for a duplicate candidate.

Comment: @RobinMackenzie That is why I did not actually vote, but that answer is a canonical answer for the null reference problem. It is good enough to explain the principle, and VB.NET is a particularly good match to VBA in this regard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a proposal, that will copy the value and the format as well

```
For i = 2 To 161672
  If cgmfitbit.Worksheets(1).Cells(i, 2).Value = ptnames Then
    cgmfitbit.Worksheets(1).Range("A" & i & ":P" & i).copy ptfile.Worksheets(1).Range("A" & i)
  End If
Next i
```